# How to make tkinter button append or replace text in label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Newbie here!

[Calculator gui.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBGyT.png)

So I'm in the process of designing a basic calculator with python and tkinter. I have created a button representing the number "1" on the calculator:

```
button_1 = tk.Button(bottomframe, text='1', width=button_WIDTH, height=button_HEIGHT, command=add_one)
button_1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
```

This is the label were the numbers are going to be inputted to:

```
display_text = tk.StringVar()
toplabel = tk.Label(labelframe, width=15, textvariable=display_text, bg='black', fg='white', anchor=tk.E, font=('Courier', 16))
toplabel.pack()
```

I also created a function to input the number as text into the label widget.

```
def add_one():
if display_text == '0':
    s = display_text.get()
    s = '1'
    display_text.set(s)
else:
    s = display_text.get()
    s += '1'
    display_text.set(s)
```

So what I'm trying to do is make the function so that if the label text is "0" (pressing "C" on calculator) the i want the next number to replace the "0". If the text is a number other then "0" then i want to of course append numbers to the label instead.
I thought that the above function would do this but i only executes the "else"-command.

Help much appreciated!

Comment: `display_text`, as a StringVar, will *never* be equal to '0'.  You have to call `.get()` on it to retrieve the actual contents.  (Just like you did on the very next line!)

Comment: Of course, great! Exactly what i needed. I'm pretty new on the get() and set() commands. Thanks!